# Feed, RSS not able to clear the cache and cannot change the limit of cache life time

Tags: filters, rss, feed

The WordPress Feed system is EXTREMELY complex for no reason.

I have been going around and around and around in circles.

I am using:

```
function do_not_cache_feeds(&$feed) {
    $feed->enable_cache(false);
}
add_action( 'wp_feed_options', 'do_not_cache_feeds' );

define( 'MAGPIE_CACHE_AGE', 1 );

function prefix_set_feed_cache_time( $seconds ) {
    return 1;
}
add_filter( 'wp_feed_cache_transient_lifetime' , 'prefix_set_feed_cache_time' );
```

In my functions.php file in my themes folder.

Did not work for a reason that is beyond me.

So first questions is: Is there any way I can get rid of the caching of the feed? I am already using Varnish?

Second, for the current cached feeds how can I clear them?

Third, where the hell are they been stored? I literally look everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using W3 Total Cache or any other caching system make sure it does not cache the feeds.

WordPress uses [SimplePie](http://simplepie.org/) for parsing it's feeds. They are many things that are happening at the same time that can cause some confusion. First SimplePie does cache the feeds, I haven't figured yet how to clear it or where it is stored. But you can use this code to force it to not cache it or cache the feeds for a shorter time.

```
function do_not_cache_feeds(&$feed) {
    $feed->enable_cache(false);
}
add_action( 'wp_feed_options', 'do_not_cache_feeds' );

function prefix_set_feed_cache_time( $seconds ) {
    return 1;
}
add_filter( 'wp_feed_cache_transient_lifetime' , 'prefix_set_feed_cache_time' );
```

Also when testing make sure you clear your browser cache. Because SimplePie with WordPress uses [HTTPCG (HTTP Conditional Get)](http://fishbowl.pastiche.org/2002/10/21/http_conditional_get_for_rss_hackers/). For more details about SimplePie caching go here: [SimplePie caching](http://simplepie.org/wiki/faq/how_does_simplepie_s_caching_http_conditional_get_system_work).